# Why is the set $\{ 0 \}$ not open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as

$ f(x) := \begin{cases}
1 &  \text{if }x=0,  \\
0 &  \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

Then $f^{-1}\big(\big(\frac{1}{2}, 2\big)\big)=\{ 0 \}$, which is not open.

Why is the set $\{ 0 \}$ not open?

Comment: What is the definition of an open set? That alone should answer your question. Or do you wonder how it could hapen that a function that is continuous on $(1/2,2)$ doesn't have an inverse that maps $(1/2,2)$ to an open set? This is because $f$ has no inverse function on that interval.

Comment: I believe the definition that I have encountered was that a set is open if for every point in the set is an interior point.

Comment: Correct. Is $0$ an interior point of the set $\{ 0\}$ ? Your definition of interior point shoulf be that there is a ball of some radius around $0$ contained in the set $\{ 0\}$. That's not there, so you would say your set is not open.

Comment: But any radius around 0 would be outside of the set {0}, so 0 is not an interior point, hence the set is not open. Is my logic correct?

Comment: Yes @huehue that ball of positive radius cannot fit in your set - and you're done.

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote and accept my answer below, if you are happy.  Feel free to ask more questions too @huehue :)

Comment: @User001 if it's not too much hassle would you be able to show me how to show a set is closed by taking a convergent sequence?

Comment: Yes, for example your set has the trivial sequence 0,0...,0 that converges to 0, which is in your set.  Or, consider [0,1] and take any convergent seq and check it.  Nice ex. would be 1/n, which lives in your set.  Also, for comparison, check this same sequence on (0,1].

Comment: @huehue to show a set is closed, *every* convergent seq in your set must converge to a point in your set.  You obv cannot check every seq.  So it's better to use this to show your set is not closed (e.g., just takes one counter-example, say, 1/n, on (0,1] ) rather than closed.  To show a set is closed, you may want to show the set is not open.

Comment: As a side note, the function $f$ in the question is not continuous, so even though $(\frac{1}{2},2)$ is open, you can say nothing about its preimage by $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to be more accurate:

Since the point $0$ cannot be an interior point of your set, the set {0} cannot be an open set.

Comment: A set that is closed isn't necessarily not open. Take the empty set for example, I believe that it is open and closed

Comment: Right, as well as the real line, @huehue.

Comment: @HueHue If a set isn't non-empty or $\mathbb{R}$ itself, then this set cannot be closed and open at the same time (with respect to standard topology).

Comment: Agreed, @Kimmel :)

Comment: @User001: Sorry, that comment was intended for HueHue. I forgot to mention his/her name :)

Comment: @Kimmel Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @user001  Thanks for your help as well :)

Comment: Dear Downvoters:  I have edited the answer, after thinking a bit more about the question and comments.  Please up-vote if you think the answer is fine now or please comment further.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't choose any neighborhood of 0 which contains a point other than 0. Because if any point come in nbd of 0 then it's image should also have 1 . But in your set ,  0 is only element which maps to 1.

So o lies in set but not interior poiny. Which leads to non oponess of set.